# Write function outputs to file in javascript

Tags: javascript

This might not even be an actual question, just a curiosity. I am currently learning up on  `array.sort()` from [MDN-Array.Sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). It says in the 'Return Value': "The sorted array. Note that **the array is sorted in place, and no copy is made**." 
So my question is could you make a copy of it? and if so how? and if not, why?
My apologies in advance if this seems like a ridiculous question, I am just trying to learn the methods as I go.

Many Thanks

Comment: "copy" not in the sense of a printed paper or a file on your computer. Copy in the sense that the array would exist twice in memory. You can copy arrays with `.slice`.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/K4phN07m

Comment: aye, basically I thought if there was a way to have the new sorted array saved on a file somewhere as an output, if that was at all possible. However I was looking over the examples given by @TJBlackman and kind of have a better understanding of how the array.sort() method works.